# Python selenium: js button downloads csv - load as dataframe?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm building a web scraper to automate the process of downloading tweet data using selenium and the headless chrome browser.

I've written a function which logs into twitter, navigates to the analytics page and downloads the csv file, but is there any way to use the pandas.read_csv function to read csv from the source directly without downloading as an intermediary step? I'm pushing data to a SQL database and eventually want to schedule on AWS Lambda so would be good if I could eliminate the need for creating new files.

code as follows (twt is how i've called TwitterBrowser() in the if **name** == "**main**": line)

```
class TwitterBrowser:
    def __init__(self):
        global LOGIN, PASSWORD, browser

        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
        chrome_driver = os.getcwd() +"\\chromedriver.exe"

        browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)

        parser = ConfigParser()    
        parser.read("apikeys.ini")
        LOGIN = parser.get('TWITTER', 'USERNAME')
        PASSWORD = parser.get('TWITTER', 'PASSWORD')

    def get_url(self, url, sec):
        load_page = browser.get(url)
        try:
            WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=sec)
        except TimeoutException:
            print('TIMED OUT!')
        return load_page

    def login(self):
        twt.get_url('https://twitter.com/login', 5)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-container"]/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[1]/input').send_keys(LOGIN)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-container"]/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[2]/input').send_keys(PASSWORD)
        WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-container"]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/button').click()

    def tweet_analytics(self):
        twt.get_url('https://analytics.twitter.com/user/'+LOGIN+'/tweets', 5)
        WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div').click()
        WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/ul/li[1]').click()
        WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="export"]/button/span[2]').click()
        WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
```

Comment: @Fraster Watt Did you get a chance to overcome this ;i have a same requirement ,Maybe any result would help me too ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632860/python-selenium-web-scrape-embedded-excel-in-xpath-to-pandas-frame-convert-logic

Answer (score 0):

Pandas can read csv directly from url as stated [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv). So I'd get the raw csv link and read it directly. I'm not sure tho if Twitter analytics has the raw csv hosted on their server ([raw csv exemple](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv)) or they generate a download link, generating the csv on the fly, where you'd be stuck, which is probably the case as I don't see them hosting unnecessary csvs.

In case you have to download it, you can then read it from you